# Access to posting company share denied in Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

One of our customers facing this issue while posting company update via our linkedin app. He has provided wshare permission. Also he has admin permission in company page and company share also enabled.

Error message:

{,"errorCode":0,"message":"Access to posting a company share denied.","status":403,"timestamp":1514400297108}}

API Endpoint : /v1/companies/{company-id}/shares

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution? Thanks.